# Sum with non-existing object in R

Tags: r

I want to make a simple script where I'll sum some variables according to a fixed naming scheme. But the problem is, not all variables will be used every time. But if I try something like this:

```
result <- sum(variable1, variable2, variable3, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I get an error saying there's no `variable1`. Is there a way to sum only the existing variables and ignore the non-existing ones without declaring all possible variables as NA beforehand?

Comment: Why not use a single variable which represents a data structure? Whenever you find yourself using large numbers of variables whose names differ only in an integer suffix, it is a clear sign of a vector /list/dataframe waiting to be born.

Comment: E.g., `variable <- numeric(); variable[1] <- 1; variable[2] <- -8; sum(variable, na.rm = TRUE)`. "fixed naming scheme" with numbers means you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Roland These are just examples, my fixed naming scheme consists of variables J, K, R, JK, JR, KR and JKR. The script divides overall shopping cost between household members

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Use an appropriate data structure. You can have that naming scheme within the data structure.

Comment: If you are going to use 7 fixed variables, is it really so hard to initialize them all to NA at the top of the script? That (or an appropriate data structure such as a dataframe) is simply more readable than using the accepted answer.

Comment: @Roland It makes input easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937148/write-script-to-ignore-objects-which-can-t-be-found-in-r)

Add this before:

```
sapply(c("variable1", "variable2", "variable3"), function(x) 
  if(!exists(x)) { assign(x, NA, envir=.GlobalEnv) } 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the variables which are available in the global environment and `sum` them.

```
#Dummy variables
variable2 <- 12
variable3 <- 3

sum(unlist(mget(ls(pattern = 'variable\\d+'))), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 15
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do

```
 Reduce(`+`, mget(ls(pattern = '^variable\\d+$')))
[1] 15
```

#### data

```
variable2 <- 12
variable3 <- 3
```